# HTML5 SpeechSynthesis API: how is the list of available voices populated?

Tags: html, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Chrome (since v33) and Firefox (since v49) support the HTML Web Speech Synthesis API.

When calling `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()`, you get the list of available voices.

I wonder how is this list populated on different platforms and in different browsers. Is there some possibility for the users to install new voices?

The [specification draft](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html#dfn-ttsgetvoices) doesn't mention any specific ways of populating the list of voices, nor does [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices) or [Google developer](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API).